# Python/Kivy: Creating attributes in constructor

Tags: python, kivy

I am getting confused, which I think means I am about to learn something new about Python.
I wish to add some attributes to an object. Later on I will check for the presence of these attributes and take action. So as part of a .kv file, I have my object (a black box with a Label and a white line around it):

```
<Box>:
    txt: txt
    id: txt
    ccolor: 0, 0, 0, 1
    on_color: 0, 0, 1, 1
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: self.ccolor
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
        Color:
            rgba: 1, 1, 1, 1
        Line:
            width: 1.
            rectangle: (self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height)
    halign: 'center'
```

And back in .py land, I have

```
class Box(Label):
    txt = ObjectProperty()
```

...

```
b = Box(ccolor = (1, 0, 0, 1))
b = Box(on_color = (1, 0, 0, 1))
```

The first invocation apparently does as I wish, setting ccolor.
The second invocation fails:

```
[WARNING           ] stderr:   File "gdisp.py", line 218, in new_data
[WARNING           ] stderr:     b = Box(on_color = (1, 0, 0, 1))
[WARNING           ] stderr:   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\label.py", line 266, in __init__
[WARNING           ] stderr:     super(Label, self).__init__(**kwargs)
[WARNING           ] stderr:   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\widget.py", line 324, in __init__
[WARNING           ] stderr:     self.bind(**on_args)
[WARNING           ] stderr:   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 430, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.bind (kivy\_event.c:5903)
[WARNING           ] stderr: AssertionError: (1, 0, 0, 1) is not callable
```

I don't understand why the first one works, but not the second.
I have tried playing with __init__ to no avail. I suspect that's where the answer lies.

For extra credit, I wish the following (or similar) to work (if it is more complicated):

```
s = "on_color = (1, 1, 1, 1), off_color = (0, 0, 0, 1)"
Box(s)
```

The end idea is to have a Box with a label that changes to one of two user-selected colors depending on a condition.
(Hmmm, what's all that txt: stuff? Fiddling detritus)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Box` is a subclass of `Label`. `Label` has a property called `color`, which controls the text colour. All properties automatically make available an event `on_propertyname`, i.e. here `on_color`, which triggers when the property value is changed. This event cannot just be a statement, it must be code that will be called (it doesn't make sense to just be a value).

Here, you apparently want `on_color` to be the name of a property, but this conflicts with the existing event. I'm not sure if properties can even have names starting with `on_`, possibly this will conflict with the event system in a more general way.

The solution seems to be to just use a different name, such as `active_color`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out what should have been obvious! Maybe color_on :)